# Como visualizar dominio DNS apenas com o número de IP?

Tags: php, ip, dns, ping

quando damos um ping em um endereço URL tipo www.google.com o prompt nos retorna o IP 172.217.30.4, agora gostaria de saber como faço para conseguir o endereço URL apenas com o número de IP através de PHP, preferencialmente. Desde já agradeço a compreensão de todos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621682/reverse-ip-find-domain-names-on-ip-address,

Comment: @MagicHat não entendi o motivo da negativação, essa pergunta feita por ele não tem no SOPT.

Comment: @HiagoSouza é por que você acha que eu sei o motivo da negativação, ou você está insinuando que foi eu quem negativou?

Comment: @MagicHat é que eu vi o seu comentário então achei que tiha sido você, se não foi perdão.

Answer (score 2):

O que você está descrevendo é um [Reverse DNS Lookup](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).

Em PHP você pode utilizar a função [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gethostbyaddr.php) para resolver nomes através de um ip. Isso não significa que você vai obter o domínio principal a partir de um ip.

```
<?php

    echo gethostbyaddr("172.217.30.4"); // rio01s23-in-f4.1e100.net

?>
```

É necessário fazer um lookup nos [DNS Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) para obter essas informações(A, CNAME, PTR e etc). Pra isso existe a função [dns_get_record](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dns-get-record.php):

```
<?php

   echo var_dump(dns_get_record("google.com"));

?>
```

Comment: Muito bom, essas dicas vão ajudar bastante.